# Why we use a complex equation when do convert RGB to YCBCR instead of a simple one?

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb

When I do implement RGB2YCBCR on verilog. I saw several ways to convert RGB to YCBCR. Some of it are very simple. But others are quite complex.

For example, if we use

```
y = (r >> 2) + (g >> 1) + (b >> 2);
```

it is very easy to implement to hardware

But some people say that

```
y = (r*4899 + g*9617+ b*1868+ 8192) >> 14
```

is faster???

I don't know why they have this equation and why a complex equation better than a simple equation. And WHY THEY USE IT instead of that simple equation.

P/S: I saw that OpenCV also uses that complex one.
Thank a lot!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion

Comment: hi there, I read this article, but I didn't find the answer to my question

Comment: _simpler_ doesn't mean _correct_. Those constants aren't there to make it more difficult, but to make it right according to the standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On processors with a multiplier and a barrel shifter, all these operations take a single clock cycle and the second formula cannot be faster (5 ops vs. 7).

The *complex* equation is mandated by a standard coming from the television technology, with historical and technological reasons (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601).

Color spaces is a rather complex topic.

---

Note that the first formula is not normalized: if the input values are in range [0,1], the outputs are in [0, 10], and you should divide by 10. This would make the first formula much slower.

Comment: Can you tell my why we use y = (4899R + 9617G + 1868B+ 8192) >> 14 
 instead of Y = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B. I think it's the same equation.

Comment: Obviously to stay in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Any idea if I do equation y = (153R + 300G + 74B + 512) >> 9.

Comment: @LuanNguyen: this is less accurate.

Comment: why  y = (4899R + 9617G + 1868B+ 8192) >> 14  is correct?
why  y = (153R + 300G + 74B + 512) >> 9 isnt correct?. I think they have same result

Comment: @LuanNguyen: no they don't.